# jQuery: Adding a class to all downloadable links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, selector, external, internal

I'm trying to add a `.dl` class to all links that have **any** file suffixes (extensions) except `.pdf` and `.html`. I don't want my other (both external and internal) links to be affected.

```
$('a').not("a[href^='http://'], a[href^='https://'], a[href^='/'], a[href^='./'], a[href^='../'], a[href^='#'], a[href$='.pdf'], a[href$='.html']").addClass( 'dl' );
```

With my code some relative and external links get affected. What can I do to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Just wondering can't you select the links which should be affected instead of removing the others?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Good point...

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze I have many different file suffixes. Maybe there is a way to check if links have suffixes then it's possible. But I didn't find a solution how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach you may can consider to try.

The filename array represents all suffixes which you want to add the class.

```js
var fileNames = ["suffix1", "suffix2"];

$("a").each(function(index, element){
  fileNames.forEach(function(fileName){
    if($(element).attr("href").startsWith(fileName)){
      $(element).addClass("dl");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dl {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="suffix1">addClass suffix1</a>
<a href="http://">don't add</a>
<a href="suffix2">addClass suffix2</a>
<a href="https://">don't add</a>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it wouldn't work in my case as I can have ANY file suffixes (extensions). I need to find another way except just listing all of them.

Comment: @jphawk yeah then it seems like your approach is quite right. Can't you add the class to the content before?

Comment: no, that was not an option. I solved the problem by using some Javascript inside jQuery filter() function. Checked the last part (after the last '/' in a link) of all my links for dots and excluded .pdf and .html separately with .not() in jQuery. But it is still interesting if it is possible to do it without mixing jQuery and Javascript, in pure jQuery.

Comment: @jphawk you may could try `a[href$=':not(:contains(".pdf")']`